# Lower duty cycle less efficient?

Tags: pwm, heat, power-dissipation, duty-cycle, switching-losses

Assume you have a DC voltage `V`, ideal switch (no switching losses) operating at some frequency `f` and duty cycle `D` (in [0,1]), and a purely resistive load `R`.

[image]

If you double `V` and halve `D`, does the average power dissipation double?  I.e., does the average power dissipation always equal the integration of the instantaneous power dissipations, as follows?  $$ P_{avg} 
= \int_{0}^{D} \frac{V^2}{R} dt = \frac{V^2}{R}D$$

Or is there some "practical" frequency (e.g. 100Hz, 10kHz) at which the heating due to current averages out enough such that the following holds? $$ P_{avg} = \frac{V_{R\_avg}^2}{R} = I^2_{R\_avg} R $$

I saw the following post, which mentioned that at "high enough" frequencies (e.g. 20kHz), the "thermal time constant" of a resistor filters out the instantaneous heat dissipation: https://www.edaboard.com/threads/resistor-power-dissipation.176648/post-742416

If this applies for resistors, does it also apply to the ESR of inductors and capacitors?

Thanks

---

**Edit:** So my understanding after getting responses is that `P_avg` (power drawn from the supply) always corresponds to the first equation.  However, the thermal effects on the resistor (or any device passing current) may not be as non-linear (i.e. more in line with the second equation), presumably due to the fact that higher instantaneous "heat surges" in the device will more quickly equilibrate than a constant heat due to some non-linear conduction phenomena.

So one should always use the RMS (*not* the average) voltage or current, not the average for calculating power dissipation, as also shown here: https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/how-to-derive-the-rms-value-of-pulse-and-square-waveforms/

Comment: Nothing mystical happens. Your math is sound, and your approach is valid/correct. Thermal averaging may occur in a resistor but that only has to do with dissipation limits. If you have a half watt resistor, you can probably dissipate 1 Watt at D=0.5 when you are switching fast. Fast means that the switching period is substantially shorter than the resistor thermal time constant. There is not one frequency that applies to all resistors.

Comment: @mkeith So if switching across a resistor at 10kHz, the average power dissipation corresponds to the first or second equation above?

Comment: The first. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Average power dissipated by a resistor is always the mean value of the instantaneous power over one period (assuming periodic waveform).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this specific case, the power dissipated by the resistor would double.

The more general principal, which is always applicable in all cases is that the average power dissipated by a resistor is the mean value of the instantaneous power calculated over one period.

So even if you have an irregular or arbitrary repeating voltage or current waveform, you can calculate the average power using the mean value of the instantaneous power. Instantaneous power can be calculated using V(t)^2/R or I(t)^2 * R or V(t) * I(t). Obviously you must calculate the mean over one period (or any whole number of periods). You can't calculate mean power over a fraction of a period.

Answer (score 2):

> *If you double V and halve D, does the average power dissipation
> double?*

Yes it does and it's easily proven by inspection and simple numbers. If R = 1, D = 0.5 and V = 1 volt, the power is 50% of 1²/1 = 0.5 watts. If V doubles to 2 and D halves to 0.25 then the power is 25% of 2²/1 = 1 watt.

It applies to any resistor and has nothing to do with thermal time constant.

Comment: So the linked poster was incorrect, and also, buck converters with higher input voltage and lower duty cycle (but same average output voltage/current) are less efficient due to higher current ripple dissipating non-linearly (quadratically) in inductor/capacitor/switch?

Comment: Yes, that is true that lower duty cycles are less efficient.

Comment: But with physical switches such as FETs, higher switching frequency increases switching losses.

Comment: @abc _"So the linked poster was incorrect"_ - in what way was it 'incorrect'?